# CSS Image Issue

Tags: css

I am trying to enable an image to appear next to some text within an anchor tag, and I'm unable to figure out how to do this.

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/V9nBZ/

The small modify image should appear next to the name "John" as illustrated:
[image]

I tried this in my page, and the image seemed to repeat.

I dont have enough CSS experience, and I would appreciate any help in setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used this in your CSS:

```
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/B7YTA.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

That is invalid CSS. You can see the image if you do:

```
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/B7YTA.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Just using `background-image` means you can only put the url to the image - nothing else.

Comment: thanks! could you tell me how I could vertically align this image as well?  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/V9nBZ/

Comment: @Paul you just need to add 8px to the background-y position so: `background: url("http://i.imgur.com/B7YTA.png") no-repeat 0 8px;`